# What is the difference between global and local configuration in git?

Tags: git, git-config

I am a beginner to Git. I go through the internet and find those.

What I know are

- **Local** -: Values in this file apply to a single repository.
- **Global** -: Configuration values in this file are applied to a single user.

Can I know any other differences between these configurations?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 42):

Git comes with a tool called `git config` that lets you configure variables that control all the aspects of how git will operate.

`git config` holds its value between upgrades. So, you need to set it only once.

Basically, there are 3 places to store these variables:

1. System.
2. Global.
3. Local.

---

**1. System**: These variables are available for every user in the system and stored in

`[path]/etc/gitconfig`. 
Example: `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig`

You can make git read and write from **System** by passing `--system` as option. It also requires you to have administration permissions.

---

**2. Global**: Global configurations are available for the current user for all the projects and stored in

`~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` 
Example: `C:/Users/Username/.gitconfig`

You can make git to read and write from **Global** by passing `--global` option.

---

**3. Local**: Local configs are available for the current repository only  and stored in

`[gitrepo]/.git/config`
Example: `C:/Users/MyProject/.git/config`

You can make git read and write from **Local** by passing `--local` option.

---

##### Example:

```
Create a local config
$ git config --local user.name "Local User"

# Create a global config
$ git config --global user.name "Global User"

# Create a system config
$ sudo git config --system user.name "System User"
```

to verify the origin of your configuration :

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Also, its important to remember each level overrides values the previous level.

Priority:

Local > Global > System

Comment: There is since last year `--show-scope` which names the level.

Comment: The best comes last..Btw "If you don’t specify which level you want to work with, this, **local** is the **default**" as another answer here states.

Comment: About `--show-scope` use it as `git config --list --show-scope`

Comment: BTW for `macOS` the location for `system` is at `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`

Answer (score 37):

Git uses a hierarchical config approach in which settings of a broader scope are inherited if not overriden.

On the top level is the system config (all users, usually in `/etc/git`), then there is the global config (which can override system defaults with personal ones, located in the home directory of the user, e.g. `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `$HOME/.config/git/config`) and finally there is the local config for a repository (`.git/config` in the repository root) which can override all above and set repository specific options.

All configuration files have the same syntax, but a different scope.

This offers a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Which one is more used `.gitconfig` or `.config/git/config`? I think the first.

Comment: The first is more common I think

Comment: If you use Git for WIndows and `%HOME%` is not set, Git uses `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Comment: BTW for `macOS` the location for `system` is at `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`

Answer (score 8):

Local level configuration is applied to the context repository git config gets invoked in. Local configuration values are stored in a file that can be found in the repo's `.git` directory: `.git/config`. If you don’t specify which level you want to work with, this is the default.

Whereas, global configuration values are stored in a file that is located in a user's home directory. `~ /.gitconfig` on Unix systems and `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` on windows

Answer (score 0):

Just a little note, as opposed to other comments mentioned here, typing
"git config --list" will output hybrid config values and not only local config.
In other words, the default of "git config --list" in a project
is not --local

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).