# I'm getting error while setting Notepad++ as the default Git editor for commits

Tags: git, git-config

I've been trying to set Notepad++ as my default editor from **Git-bash** but when I run this command:

```
git config core.editor "notepad++ -multiInst -nosession"
```

I get this error:

> fatal: not in a git directory

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you running that command in a git repository?

Comment: Yes, I'm using $ MINGW64 GIT. I think I could set it. but when I open the notepad++ from git bash, then it opens the last opened tab. how I can make it to open completely a new instance of the notepad++ editor?

Comment: Most of the time, "git directory" means a working copy.  You're likely running this command in a random directory, and the solution for this is already in an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I set notepad++ as my git commit editor in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389455/why-cant-i-set-notepad-as-my-git-commit-editor-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten something in your command in your Git :
if you're running x64 machine then try this command

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

The exact location of notepad++ should be placed there with the necessary parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure if whether or not it's an x64 machine is relevant for this error.

Comment: It worked. but when I try to open Notepad++ from Git Bash, then it opens the previously opened tab. How can I create a new instance when I call Notepad++ from Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

`git config` by default affects the configuration for a specific repository. If you are not in a repository you will get the error you have seen.

If you want to make a user-wide configuration that is not specific to a  repository, use `git config --global` instead.

See: [What is the difference between global and local configuration in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202175/what-is-the-difference-between-global-and-local-configuration-in-git)